# Помогите с питоном не могу понять как сделать чтобы с информации Entry рисовались на канвасе Фигуры

Tags: python, tkinter

Помогите с питоном не могу понять как сделать чтобы с информации Entry рисовались на канвасе Фигуры
Вот весь код

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('800x600')
tk.title('Your House')
tk.resizable(height=False, width=False)
c = Canvas(tk, width=300, height=300, bg='white')
c.place(x=400, y =200)
entry_resizableWall = Entry(tk, bd=4, bg='#FFFAFA', font='Arial 12')
entry_resizableWall.place(x=60, y=80)
entry_resizableRoof = Entry(tk, bd=4, bg='#FFFAFA', font='Arial 12')
entry_resizableRoof.place(x=60, y=180)
entry_colorWall = Entry(tk, bd=4, bg='#FFFAFA', font='Arial 12')
entry_colorWall.place(x=60, y=280)
entry_colorRoof = Entry(tk, bd=4, bg='#FFFAFA', font='Arial 12')
entry_colorRoof.place(x=60, y=380)
label_resizableWall = Label(tk, text='Resizable for Wall: (x1,y1,x2,y2)', font='Arial 12')
label_resizableWall.place(x=60, y = 30)
label_resizableRoof = Label(tk, text='Resizable for Roof: (x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3(1Left, 2Up, 3Right))', font='Arial 12')
label_resizableRoof.place(x=60, y = 130)
label_colorWall = Label(tk, text='Color for Wall', font='Arial 12')
label_colorWall.place(x=60, y = 230)
label_colorRoof = Label(tk, text='Color for Roof', font='Arial 12')
label_colorRoof.place(x=60, y = 330)
labelCanvasResizable = Label(text='Canvas Widht/Height 300x300')

def GetAll():
    b = entry_resizableWall.get()
    int(b)
    entry_resizableRoofGet = entry_resizableRoof.get()
    entry_colorWallGet = entry_colorWall.get()
    entry_colorRoofGet = entry_colorRoof.get()
    #print(type(entry_resizableWallGet))
    c.create_rectangle(b)



btn_create = Button(tk, text='Create', font='Arial 25', padx=35, pady=20, bg='#FFFAFA', command=GetAll)
btn_create.place(x=60,y=450)






'''
c.create_rectangle(30, 60, 130, 120, fill='green')

c.create_polygon(30, 60, 80, 10, 130, 60, fill='blue')
'''
mainloop()
```

Comment: Уточните, что конкретно не понятно. Если нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопки рисовалось, то в обработчике нажатия на кнопки и создавайте фигуры.